Shift geom by same visual proportion on a transformed scale
I make a plot with a log10() transformed x axis and I want to add labels to it. Let's assume I am making a scatter plot and for some reason I want to label the points. I do not want the points and letters to overlap, therefore I shift the labels a little to the right. R Code:
n <- 5
df <- data.frame(x= seq(.1, 3, length.out= n), y= 1:n, lab= letters[1:n])
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, col= lab), show.legend= FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(x + 1, y, label= lab, col= lab), show.legend= FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(transform= "log10")


Because of the transformation the shift between the first point (.1,1) and its label ("a") seems much bigger than the other. How to add labels that all have the same visual shift from their points? I tried all kind of things, but the visual gap between point and label always varies.

Stefan has a great answer. But you could also do this without stage() by multiplying the x-coordinate in geom_text instead of adding. Because multiplying on a linear scale is the same as adding on a log scale, if you multiply by a constant the labels will be shifted by the same amount. For example geom_text(aes(x * 1.1, y, ...)

@qdread That is great and in my opinion worth being an answer

A possible solution, that will work with any plotting package, is to take advantage of the fact that multiplying on a linear scale is the same as adding on a log scale. If you multiply the x-coordinate by a constant on the original scale, and then log-transform, you will get labels that are each shifted by the same amount on the new log scale. If the constant is >1, they will be shifted to the right. For example:
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, col = lab), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(x * 1.1, y, label = lab, col = lab), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(transform = "log10")

In this case, turning off clipping is not necessary because the scale will expand to accommodate the labels.

I like this solution a lot. My actual usecase is more complicated than the dummy data and the labels sometimes need to be right or left from the point. This can be easily achieved with your solution by using x * .9, for example. So I changed my code to your answer. Thanks!

I would say @stefan 's answer may potentially be more useful for ggplot2 in general because it will work with any transformation. My answer will only work in the special case of the log transformation. I just wanted to provide an alternative.

In my special usecase where the position (left/ right) depends on the x values itself, your code was easier to adapt. But you are right that stefan provided a more general approach

One option would be to use stage() to shift the positions by an equal amount after the transformation via the scale has been applied:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, col = lab), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      stage(x, after_scale = x + .1),
      y,
      label = lab, col = lab
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(transform = "log10")


UPDATE To fix the issue with clipped off label you can expand the scale additively by the same or a somewhat larger amount used to shift the labels. (Additionally I added coord_cartesian(clip = "off") to prevent that the labels get clipped off).
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y, col = lab), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      stage(x, after_scale = x + .1),
      y,
      label = lab, col = lab
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    transform = "log10",
    expand = expansion(mult = c(.05, 0), add = c(0, .125))
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")



This is very nice! How to hinder the code to cut off the plot? Letter "e" is not on the plot anymore. I can't set manually limits since they vary with the data..

See my update for a possible option.
